# Adding a class (arrows) to main menu links that have children?

Tags: menus, javascript, walker

I'm wondering if it is possible to add different classes to second/third/fourth/etc-level items that have children in Appearance > Menus tree?

That's how I call the menu:

```
 <?php $menu_args = array(
    'container'       => '', 
    'menu_class'      => '', 
    'menu_id'         => 'my-menu',
    'walker'          => new Description_Walker);

    wp_nav_menu($menu_args );   
 ?>
```

I know every link owns different ID like `<li id="menu-item-3230">`, but I want the solution to be dynamic so I won't have to edit code every time I change something. I guess the easiest way will be to attach additional class to these items but how?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

- Javascript. You could use JQuery to select the `<li>` that have  `<ul>` children of class 'sub-menu', inserting content, or appending a CSS class which you then style. For example: `$('.sub-menu').parent().addClass('myclass')`
- PHP, a new walker function. Copy the code from wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php (until approx line 109) into your themes functions.php to create a new walker. Pass this walker as an argument to your menu call. In the modified Walker insert a  `<span>` for an arrow on a sub-menu level item.

  ```
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
      $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
      $output .= "\n$indent<span class=\"right-arrow\">&rarr;</span><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
  }
  ```

  This will add a small arrow that you can then style just before the sub-menu list item.

Answer (score 5):

You can extend the menu walker, and add a "has_children" class on items that have sub-menus:

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
  public function display_element($el, &$children, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output){
    $id = $this->db_fields['id'];    

    if(isset($children[$el->$id]))
      $el->classes[] = 'has_children';    

    parent::display_element($el, $children, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
  }
}
```

and pass your instance of the class as argument in [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu):

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location'  => 'whatever',
  'walker'          => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
));
```

Then add your arrow with CSS, like Philip posted:

```
li.has_children > a:after { content: " →"; }
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to add a custom CSS class when you're creating/editing your menu in the admin. If you don't already see the CSS option box, go to screen options on the menu admin page and tick it.

Answer (score 2):

with css you can also use the [content property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp), 
something like this must do the job,

```
#div-id ul li a:after { content: " →"; }
```