# Add "sub-nav" class to a sub menu parent item

Tags: css, menus, links, sub-menu

i have a problem. I have an CSS Dropdown Menu. The HTML Code of the is this:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Archiv</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav">Kontakt</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Submenue 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenue 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenue 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
</ul>
```

WordPress makes them into the following:

```
<ul id="nav" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-636" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-636">
    <li id="menu-item-614" class="sub-nav menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-614">
    <li id="menu-item-615" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-615">
        <a href="http://welitso.de/2010?preview=1&template=welitso_html5&stylesheet=welitso_html5" title="archiv">Archiv</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenue 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1013" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1013">
</ul>
```

How can i tell WordPress that the link on "menu-item-615" should have the a-class "sub-nav" ?

Comment: I posted an answer to an almost identical question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36178/1986). Use that code, and change 'has_children` with your `sub-nav` class.

Comment: Thank you. Now i get the class in the "li" element. How can i put this as a link class to the link in this li element? --> <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav">Entry 1</a></li>

Comment: You don't need it on the link; just use `... li.sub-nav > a` when selecting the element

Answer (score 1):

This is tested, this will take all your sub nav and add the class.

```
$('#nav li > ul').parent().children("a").addClass("sub-nav");
```

Comment: Thanks but i think that adds an class to the ul. I need it in a link tag.

Comment: try my edited code, you can just add an `a` after the class selector

Comment: That would only affect on this link (615)? If I add more such links, I would have to repeat this ever and ever. Is there any possibility, menu entries with a sub-menu provide with a class?

Comment: check my edit, now the above code will apply on all the sub menu only if it has

Comment: Thanks! :) But i dint understand how should i past this? In the wp_nav_menu code?

Comment: This is javascript/jquery. Not the best option in my opinion...

Comment: @One Trick Pony What dou you think is the best opinion to realize that?

Comment: Buuuuuh, I don't like this answer :|