# How to add an <img> tag when a menu item is a dropdown(or has a sub-menu)

Tags: menus, dropdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a class (arrows) to main menu links that have children?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30139/adding-a-class-arrows-to-main-menu-links-that-have-children)

I have two, very basic css dropdowns in my menu. I want to be able to add an arrow next to the dropdowns like shown below.

[image: ss]

What I want to do is basicly use wp_nav_menu's 'after' argument, only if the item has a submenu. I'm guessing I need to add a filter but I have no idea how that works. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use CSS to add the arrow, each sum menu gets a class of `sub-menu` by default

Comment: Actually I can't. There is no backward selectors in css. I can't target the <a> before the sub-menu, and there is no differentiating class for the ones with a sub-menu in it. And I can't give that image to the sub-menu because of my "overflow:none"s.

Comment: via custom walker and css by adding a class to li's that have submenus: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/add-has-children-class-to-parent-li-when-modifying-walker-nav-menu

Comment: @Milo yeah that looks like what I'm after but can you help me a bit here? obviously  "if ( $args->has_children ) {
            // ...
        }" is where I should add my img tags but I really don't know how to do that. would it work if I wrote $after='<img src="" />' in there?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer in this topic: [Adding a class (arrows) to main menu links that have children?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30139/adding-a-class-arrows-to-main-menu-links-that-have-children?rq=1)

It's pretty genius actually. Copies the original walker function to add your html when the wp is writing the sub-menu uls. Thanks awesome guy.